# How to get count of records with same attribute value?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i have model, let's say "order". "Order" has an atribute, let's say, "category" (order belongs to one category)

how can i get number of records in "orders" table with same "category" as on current model?

br&tnx
Y

Comment: Is there a defined relationship between `order` and `category`? I guess I'm confused why something like `Order::where('category', $yourCategory)->count();` doesn't suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You have a relation between Order and category then in category You'll have method similar to that:

```
public function orders() {
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class, 'category_id')
}
```

Where `category_id` is foreign key in order model.

Now You can call on category model's:

```
$count = $category->orders()->count();
```

to get number of category's orders.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
$results = Order::select('category', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
             ->groupBy('category')
             ->get();
```

This will count categories in Orders.

Comment: yes, but not number of appearance of EXACT category current model is in?